# TypeScript does not recognize null validation inside methods

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
...
export default class LogProcessor {
  ...
  private readonly data: LogData[] = []

  constructor (
    ...
    private readonly parser: LogParser,
    ...
  ) {}

  async process (): Promise<void> {
    ...
    // the variable "line" is a string that is being parsed to object of type LogData on success or null on failure
    const logData = this.parser.parse(line)
    if (this.isLogDataValid(logData)) {
      this.data.push(logData)
    }
  }

  isLogDataValid (logData: LogData | null): boolean {
    return logData !== null &&
      this.isLogLevelValid(logData.loglevel)
  }

  isLogLevelValid (loglevel: string): boolean {
    // validation logic...
  }
}

...
```

Where:

- `logData` could be an `LogData` instance or `null`
- `this.data` is an `array` of `LogData` and can't contain `null` values in it
- The line `if (this.isLogDataValid(logData))...` is already validating if `logData` is `null` but TypeScript compiler keeps throwing the following error:

  ```bash
  src/LogProcessor.ts:40:26 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'LogData | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LogData'.
    Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'LogData'.

  40           this.data.push(logData)
                              ~~~~~~~


  Found 1 error in src/LogProcessor.ts:40
  ```

If I change the validation part inside the `process` method to this:

```js
const logData = this.parser.parse(line)
if (logData === null) return
if (this.isLogDataValid(logData)) {
  this.data.push(logData)
}
```

everything works fine, but I believe this is not the "elegant way".

Does anyone know if there is a way to solve this issue keeping my original code or doing something better? I want to put this null validation into a method to keep code at a single level of abstraction.

Comment: A return type of `boolean` doesn't give the compiler any information about what you intend that method to tell it about the _type_ of the argument. Write [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

Comment: Honestly, I didn't understand 100% yet of type predicates usage  but it worked! Thank you!!